# Something's wrong with my implementation of Comparable

Tags: java, collections, iterable

So I'm trying to use a treeMap to create a collection of data and then I would like to get a sorted list while using my own comparator.

My problem is that Collections.sort throws and error because `Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable` but my extsListed is of type ArrayList which indeed is Iterable as can be seen here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

```
    List<FileInfo> extsListed = new ArrayList<FileInfo>(exts.values());

    for (FileInfo info : Collections.sort(extsListed)) {
        System.out.println(info.key + ' ' + info.count + ' ' + info.size);
    }

    System.out.println(totalFound.toString() + ' ' + totalSize);
}

public static class FileInfo implements Comparable<FileInfo>{
    String key;
    Integer count;
    Long size;

    public FileInfo(String key, File file){
        count = 1;
        this.key = key;
        this.size = file.length();
    }

    public int compareTo(FileInfo other) {
        if (this.size > other.size) return 1;
        else if (this.size == other.size) {
            if (this.key.compareTo(other.key) >= 1) return 1;
            else if (this.key.equals(other.key)) return 0;
            else return -1;
        }
        else return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can write

```
public static class FileInfo implements Comparable<FileInfo>{
    String key;
    int count; // don't use a wrapper unless you want it to be null.
    long size;

    public FileInfo(String key, File file){
        count = 1;
        this.key = key;
        this.size = file.length();
    }

    public int compareTo(FileInfo other) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(size, other.size);
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = key.compareTo(other.key);
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

then you can sort the collection with

```
extsListed.sort();
```

---

Another approach is to not use Comparable at all.

```
public static class FileInfo implements Comparable<FileInfo>{
    final String key;
    final int count; // don't use a wrapper unless you want it to be null.
    final long size;

    public FileInfo(String key, File file){
        count = 1;
        this.key = key;
        this.size = file.length();
    }
    public String getKey() { return key; }
    public long getSize() { return size; }
    public String toString() { return key + ' ' + size + ' ' + count; }
}


exts.values().stream()
              .sort(comparing(FileInfo::getSize).andThen(FileInfo::getKey))
              .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Some links which might be useful

- [Java 8 javadoc for Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)
- [Java 8 - Comparison with Lambdas](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-sort-lambda)
- [Sorting in Java 8](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/)

Comment: Uuuuu I like this one. The whole time my question was why wasn't there something like this. +50

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic BTW if you are not using Java 8, perhaps you should. Java 7 is due to be EOL in April.

Comment: I have around 15h of coding in Java so it's not as much of "not using java8" and more of "not using any java" :D could you please give me some google search terms I should use to find more about this functional usage of sort

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic I added some links on the topics.  You could find some terms from those if you want to know more.

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic For me it's 15y of Java ;)

Answer (score 6):

`Collections.sort` returns `void`. It does not return the sorted collection for you. You can simply iterate over the collection itself after calling `sort`:

```
Collections.sort(extsListed);
for (FileInfo info : extsListed) {
   ...
```

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic you could have debugged & figured out the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Collections [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) is a void. So it doesn't return a value:

Change:

```
  List<FileInfo> extsListed = new ArrayList<FileInfo>(exts.values());

    for (FileInfo info : Collections.sort(extsListed)) {
        System.out.println(info.key + ' ' + info.count + ' ' + info.size);
    }
```

To:

```
   List<FileInfo> extsListed = new ArrayList<FileInfo>(exts.values());
   Collections.sort(extsListed);
    for (FileInfo info : extsListed) {
        System.out.println(info.key + ' ' + info.count + ' ' + info.size);
    }
```